# Can't access boot selection

Tags: boot, acer-aspire

I'm trying to put Debian on a PC. Right now it's under Win7.

I burned the .iso on a CD and rebooted. When I try to get into boot menu, the PC says "Please Wait..." and doesn't seem to do anything. I've been waiting for something like half an hour.

The laptop is an Acer Aspire, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From others who have experienced [similar problems](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/274223-30-acces-setup-boot-menu-boot) the solution seems to be reset the bios. You might be able to do this by entering bios at boot time or you might have to open the laptop and remove the little backup battery.